# Using is_zipfile on ZPublisher.HTTPRequest.FileUpload

Tags: python-2.7, plone, zope

I'm trying to check if an uploaded file is a valid zip file, but it seems that is_zipfile calls the read method, which sets the file string to '', so subsequent calls to read return a zero length string.

I'm trying to copy the file to have a second disposable version, but copy is just a shallow copy, and deepcopy returns an error `TypeError: object.__new__(method-wrapper) is not safe, use method-wrapper.__new__()`

I could save the file string to a variable, then call the is_zipfile method, but that returns False, as the file is effectively now an empty file.

How can I copy the FileUpload object, or call is_zipefile without it calling the read method, or verify the object is a zip file without destroying it in the process?

```
fileToImport = REQUEST.get('sourceFile', None)
if is_zipfile(fileToImport):
    file_string = fileToImport.read()
    self.importDesignFromZip(file_string, replace=replace)
else:
    xmlstring = fileToImport.read()
    self.importDesignFromXML(xmlstring, replace=replace)
```

Cheers
Michael

Plone-4.1.3
Zope 2.13.10
Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 4):

Seek back to the start of the file:

```
iszip = is_zipfile(fileToImport)
fileToImport.seek(0)
data = fileToImport.read()

if iszip:
    self.importDesignFromZip(data, replace=replace)
else:
    self.importDesignFromXML(data, replace=replace)
```